# Cast (const) char * to LPCWSTR

Tags: c++, winapi, char, wchar-t, lpcwstr

I'm trying to use `FindWindow()` from WinAPI, and I want to ask an input for window's title from the user:

```
char *input;
cout << "Window title: ";
cin >> input;
```

Pretty standard.
Now then, how do I convert this to `LPCWSTR` for `FindWindow()`?

I've already tried the following: `_T(input)`, `TEXT(input)`, `(LPCWSTR)input` but none of them worked.
I also tried using `wchar_t` instead of `char`, but I need `char` everywhere else so then I get dozens of errors for using `wchar_t` instead of `char`...

Comment: If you are going to read in an ANSI string then you may as well call `FindWindowA`. If you want to support UTF-16, then you'd better stop storing strings in ANSI char arrays.

Comment: You can use mbstowcs_s and wcstombs_s to convert to/from wide/multibyte char arrays. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyktyxsx%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d7tc9zw.aspx).

Comment: I would use strings for input and would use `MyString.c_str()` or `&MyString[0]` to give a parameter to API function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the wide variants of cin and cout:

```
wchar_t input[256];    // don't really use a fixed size buffer!
wcout << L"Window title: ";
wcin >> input;
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you think you want `LPCWSTR`? `LPCWSTR` is used in programs compiled for `UNICODE`. If you are using the char type everywhere then you should change the project property Character Set from 'Use `UNICODE` character set' to 'Use Multibyte Character Set." If you do that then `FindWindow` will accept a char array, like

```
char input[256];
```

Comment: *Why do you think you want LPCWSTR?* Clearly because the compiler said so.

Answer (score 3):

I would use:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
typedef std::wstring String;
#define Char         wchar_t
#define out          wcout
#define in           wcin
#else
typedef std::string String;
#define Char        char
#define out         cout
#define in          cin
#endif

String input;
out << _T("Window title: ");
in >> input;
FindWindow(input.c_str(), ...);
```

If you are sure if `UNICODE` is defined you can do not make definition, but I recomend to use typedef for string type and use strings instead of api pointer types because it is type safer and it is easier to read code. In that case you need to call `c_str()` method which returns pointer to the first element. Also you can use `&string[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

First you could get users input as `wchar_t*` instead of `char*`. I think it would be the best option.

---

`LPCWSTR` is a pointer to wide char array, so you need to convert every `char` to `wchar_t`.

So lets say you have:

```
char arr[] = "Some string";
```

So your actions:

```
size_t size = strlen(arr);
wchar_t* wArr = new wchar_t[size];
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    wArr[i] = arr[i];
```

And if you need `LPCWSTR` you just use `&wArr[0]` (or some other index).

**Important:** don't forget to deallocate memory.