# Remove the "\1" in the end of a Buffer string and avoid showing a value- WinAPI and C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using some Registry functions from the Windows API (`RegOpenKeyEx`, `RegQueryInfoKey` and `RegEnumValue`)Let's say this is the code I have so far:

```
const int MAX_VALUE_NAME= 16383;
const int MAX_DATA = 16383;

DWORD i;
    HKEY hKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    LPCTSTR lpSubKey = TEXT("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\RunMRU");
    DWORD ulOptions = 0;
    REGSAM samDesired = KEY_READ | KEY_WRITE | KEY_QUERY_VALUE;
    HKEY phkResult;
    DWORD dwIndex = 0;
    TCHAR lpValueName[MAX_VALUE_NAME];
    LPCTSTR ValueMRU;
    BYTE *DataMRU;
    DWORD lpcchValueName = MAX_VALUE_NAME;
    BYTE lpData[MAX_DATA+2];
    DWORD cbData = sizeof(lpData);
    DWORD type;

    TCHAR lpClass[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("");
    DWORD lpcClass = MAX_PATH;
    LPDWORD lpReserved = NULL;
    DWORD lpcSubKeys = 0;
    DWORD lpcMaxSubKeyLen;
    DWORD lpcMaxClassLen;
    DWORD lpcValues;
    DWORD lpcMaxValueNameLen;
    DWORD lpcMaxValueLen;
    DWORD lpcbSecurityDescriptor;
    FILETIME lpfLastWriteTime;
    char *pMsg = NULL;
    long R;

long OpenK = RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, lpSubKey, ulOptions, samDesired, &phkResult);

if (OpenK == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        long Query = RegQueryInfoKey(phkResult, lpClass, &lpcClass, lpReserved, &lpcSubKeys, &lpcMaxSubKeyLen,
            &lpcMaxClassLen, &lpcValues, &lpcMaxValueLen, &lpcMaxValueLen, &lpcbSecurityDescriptor, &lpfLastWriteTime);

        if (Query == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            if (lpcValues)
            {

                cout << "Number of values in the subkey: " << lpcValues << endl;
                cout << "\nThe values are:: \n" << endl;

                //Show RunMRU values and content.

                for (i = 0; i < lpcValues; i++)
                {

                    lpcchValueName = MAX_VALUE_NAME;
                    //lpValueName[0] = '\0';    
                    lpValueName[MAX_VALUE_NAME];
                    //lpData[MAX_DATA + 2];
                    cbData = MAX_DATA;


                    R = RegEnumValue(phkResult, i, lpValueName, &lpcchValueName, NULL,
                        &type, lpData, &cbData);

                    int Quantity = strlen((const char *)lpData);




                    if (R != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
                    {

                            cout << "\0" << lpValueName << ": " << lpData << endl;
                            cout << "Number of characters: " << Quantity << endl;
                            cout << "\n";



                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "Error enumerating values. Code: " << R << endl;
                    }



                }


            } //EOIF.
```

And this is what I got:

[image]

The questions are:

1. How do I remove the "\1" at the end of the string from lpData? [**Solved: See below**]

PD. lpData gets the value's content, not the value.

2. How do I avoid showing the RunMRU value without affecting the "for" and the other values and content?

**EDIT 1:** I could solve the "\1" question by adding this into the `FOR`:

```
int Quantity = strlen(lpData);
std::string original = lpData;
std::string result = original.substr(0, original.size() - 2);
std::string result = original.substr(0, Quantity - 2);

if (R != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
{
cout << "\0" << lpValueName << ": " << (TCHAR*)result.c_str() << endl; 
cout << "Numbers of characters: " << Quantity-2 << endl;
cout << "\n";

}
else 
{
cout << "Error enumerating the values. Code: " << R << endl;
}
```

Now I just need to know how to avoid showing the MRUList value within the FOR.

Comment: Copy the string, search it backwards for the last instance of "\", replace that char with 0x0 or '\0'. strrchr would be what I'd use in C.

Comment: You do realize that your program is accessing undocumented registry keys, right? Make sure your customers understand that it may stop working at any time.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* dest = new char[strlen(lpData) - 2];
memcpy(dest, lpData, strlen(lpData) - 2)

//do stuff with dest..
delete[] dest;
```

Another way is to std::string it..

```
std::string dest = std::string(lpData);
dest.erase(std::find_last_of("\\1"), 2);
```

Comment: Hi, the "find_last_of" is not found. What header do I have to add?

Comment: It is included in anything using `<string>` header. This solution isn't efficient however. Check the answer above mine. I added a comment that should help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have not only `\1`. It is possible to have `\2` or even `\100`, so my answer shows how to cut all that stuff from the end.

You need to substring you value. Try this:

```
size_t len = strlen(lpData);
for (int i = len - i; i <= 0; --i)
{
    if (lpData == '\\')
    {
        lpData[i] = '\0';
        break;
    }
}
```

You may need some other procedure instead of `strlen` depending on setting, you can choose it from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zh94ax%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Probably `wcslen`.

---

> How do I avoid showing the RunMRU value without affecting the "for"
>   and the other values and content?

It is more `C` solution then `C++` but this way performance is better. Pure `C++` solution would be connected with `std::string` and would take more clocks to get wanted result.

---

Also you may found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836391/cast-const-char-to-lpcwstr/17838574#17838574) helpful.

Comment: Thanks! But not working, because I need to initialize the len like that: size_t len = strlen((const char *)lpData); The cycle does not allow to operand BYTE with a char. 

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have UNICODE defined in your project?

Comment: I set it like "Not Set" in the Properties.

Comment: ST3's for loop is wrong.. It should be:  `for (int I = len; I > 0; --I)`  then the if statement should be: `if (lpData[I] == '\\')` Then it should work. In other words: http://pastebin.com/FMFFH7B9

Comment: However I get the same error when I am writing the "if" sentence: "Error:operand types are incompatible ("TCHAR *" and "char")" No matter if I set the lpData as BYTE or TCHAR.

Comment: Solved. See the post. I just need now how to avoid the MRUList value while printing the results. Any ideas?